# Why does ownCloud 9.0.1 install on shared hosting fails?

Tags: ssl, plesk, owncloud

I'm trying to install owncloud 9.1 on a shared hosting (kreativmedia) but i get the following error:

> Error
>   ownCloud is NOT installed
>   download of ownCloud source file failed.
>   SSL: certificate subject name '*.owncloud.com' does not match target host > name 'download.owncloud.org'SSL: certificate subject name '*.owncloud.com' > does not match target host name 'download.owncloud.org'

I've tried to change this two option in the setup-owncloud.php file to FALSE

```
    if (Setup::isCertInfoAvailable()){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CERTINFO, TRUE);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
```

but whit the same error.

I've tried to download the files via FTP, and to run the installer, it failed whith this error:

> Error
>   ownCloud is NOT installed
>   The selected folder seems to already contain a ownCloud installation. - You cannot use this script to update existing installations.

I have no admin rights on this server, just a Plesk 12 access. Any idea?

Comment: Are you using the web installer script? Maybe it's easier to do a manual installation Just remove all contents of the directory where you want to install oC, and download the tar.gz and extract it. Have a look at https://doc.owncloud.org/server/9.0/admin_manual/installation/index.html

Comment: Thx, I'm trying the manual install, I'll have to ask my hosting service for a outdated libxml librairy. (I don't anderstand the downvote frome some user, if it's because of my english, i'm french speaking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. I opened the script and I found url https://download.owncloud.org/download/community/owncloud-latest.zip
Tried in web browser and it downloads fine. Also tried without HTTPS.

So open the file setup-owncloud.php go to line 139 (or search for `https://download.owncloud.org/download/community/owncloud-latest.zip`) and replace `https` with `http`. Upload modified script to the server and try again.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's looks like you catch temporary SSL certificate's issue with download.owncloud.org:

`'.owncloud.com' does not match target host > name 'download.owncloud.org'`

Now there everything fine with http**s**://download.owncloud.org but it's forwards to owncloud.org